# Replace Multiple equal characters in String

Tags: java

A String can contain multiple spaces in a row - I need to replace multiple subsequent spaces by one single space char. The "problem" is that i cant know how many spaces there may encounter. The function I look for shall not only replace the first occurance of a found match, but all multiple equal characters in a String.

I searched a lot on the internet and tried the **regex** "**X*?**   (X, zero or more times)" which I found unter "Reluctant quantifiers" on https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum

That didnt work: `s1 = s1.replaceAll(" *?", " ");`
Where `s1 = "Hello     World";` should be converted to `s1 = "Hello World";`

I'd be thankful for any help.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `replaceAll()` that replaces whitespaces with just a single space.

```
String st = "helllo   world"
System.out.println(st.replaceAll("\\s+"," "))

Output : helllo world
```

Comment: The regexp matcher for whitespace is `\\s+` as this answer correctly pointed out.

Keep in mind though that `s1.replaceAll("\\s+", " ")` produces a new String as a result. So s1 will remain unchanged and you'll need to assign the result of replaceAll to a new variable in order to make use of the regexp replacement.